# How do I make a select list from a Viewbag item list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown

I have a list created from a controller which is passed to a viewbag item:

```
        List<SelectListItem> PTL = new List<SelectListItem>();


        List<PT> PTL2 = db.PT.ToList();



        foreach (var item in PTL2)
        {
            PTL.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.ID.ToString(), Text = item.Name });
        }

        ViewBag.PTL2 = PTL2;
```

Then, in the view, I tried the following from another question here:

```
               @Html.DropDownList("test", new SelectListItem[]{ 
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo1", Value="Exemplo1"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo2", Value="Exemplo2"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo3", Value="Exemplo3"}}
            , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

which worked fine, but, if I try to edit it to the following:

```
               @Html.DropDownList("test", ViewBag.PTL2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I get various errors.

I have spent hours on this trying different combinations, different castings and more, but, I just don't seem to be making progress.

I have seen so many different errors - the most common one being '

> There is no `ViewData` item of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that
>   has the key “test”'

However, I tried casting and changing the name as per different questions here, but, I just can't seem to get past this.

At this point, I am thinking of just making a manual HTML Drop Down list and a `foreach` loop for the content, but, this seems a waste.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Comment: You need to cast it - `@Html.DropDownList("test", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PTL2, ...)` Recommend you also read [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) and do not use `ViewBag`

Comment: Thanks, I fear I am too far along to change to not use ViewBag if it can work quick (just a small internal tool), but I will read and learn for next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter must be a collection of `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` objects that are used to populate the drop-down list. But, you are using `ViewBag` property in this case and the type of this is `dynamic`. So, you must cast it to the collection of the `SelectListItem`. Otherwise, you will get this error in MVC 4+:

> Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched

So. as a result just change 
`ViewBag.PTL2` 
to
`ViewBag.PTL2 as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: Thanks for the last edit! Was struggling understanding the double brackets and syntax/couldn't get it to compile! trying again now...

Comment: The last edit you made / as works great! Thank you very much - will mark as answer when the timer expires.

Comment: @wil Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

i hope it is not too late ,this is how i do it with .net core
in your controller ,use below code

```
 public ActionResult ShowCalendar()
        {
            var programs = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList((new Programs().GetAll().ToList(), "ID", "Name")  
 
            ViewBag.AllItems = programs;
 
            return View();
        }
```

and in your cshtml file use the below

```
            <select id="ItemID" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="ViewBag.AllItems">
                <option disabled selected>--- @Localizer["PleaseSelect"] ---</option>
            </select>
```

will do the job for you